# Countryref to dataframe

Tags: r

I came across the R *countryref* package: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/CoordinateCleaner/versions/2.0-11/topics/countryref

> A data.frame with coordinates of country and province centroids and
>   country capitals as reference for the clean_coordinates, cc_cen and
>   cc_cap functions. Coordinates are based on the Central Intelligence
>   Agency World Factbook
>   https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/ and
>   http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php.

Apparently, I can display part of the data via

```
data(countryref)
head(countryref)
```

However, my question is: How can I send the data into a new dataframe and export it as CSV?

Comment: use `CoordinateCleaner::countryref` or just `countryref` if package is loaded; `class(CoordinateCleaner::countryref)` gives data.frame. Create a new data.frame with `foo <- CoordinateCleaner::countryref; identical(foo,  CoordinateCleaner::countryref)` gives `TRUE`. Voting to close.

Comment: `df = countryref` works ... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export a data frame as csv using write.csv (for example `write.csv(x, "filename.csv")`.